# Create a bar/line in SharePoint list new form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

Can you please help me to create a line/bar in SharePoint list new form. I have set of questions in SharePoint list and they should be separate by the line. for example to first few questions should have a bar with something like basic user information. and then the next few questions should have another bar/line call user personal details.

Kind Regards

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? If SP online, classic or modern experience?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience, you can format the list forms using JSON to group the fields shown on form.

You need to configure the "body" to add sections in list form. In each section you can group the one or more columns & name the section like "basic information" or "personal details".

**Sample JSON code**:

```
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": "",
            "fields": [
                "Title"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Details",
            "fields": [
                "Department",
                "Email",
                "Country"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Application",
            "fields": [
                "Application Id",
                "Approver",
                "Reviewer"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Sample output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Configure the list form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration)

---

If you are using classic experience in SharePoint online or SharePoint Server, there is no out of the box way to achieve such requirements. You need to use custom HTML, CSS, JS for DOM manipulation to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @Harris, does this answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SharePoint On-Premise or classic experience, I will suggest you to use the [survey](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-survey-ea52a787-822e-4f7e-b5ed-77bb14df3aba) for providing questions to users.

And if still you like to add a bar/line to SharePoint list new form, you can edit the new form and insert a script editor to hold CSS style based on your requirements. An example here:https://debug.to/435/add-horizontal-line-in-sharepoint-newform-page

For modern experience, the recommended way will be using [PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-apps/get-started/create-your-first-custom-form) to customize the list form. The default list new form cannot be customized.